# Read string array with an int selector C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms, int

I have the following code to create a string array named "Lines" from pasted code and add an item for every array from the "Lines" string into a listBox.

```
string Temp = Clipboard.GetText();
int count = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < Temp.Length; i++)
{
    if (Temp[i] == '\n') count++;
}
string[] lines = Temp.Split(
new[] { Environment.NewLine },
StringSplitOptions.None
);
int reader = 1;
int repeat = count;
for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
{
    ListBox.Items.Add(lines[reader]);
    reader = reader + 1;
}
```

When this code is used in Visual Studio, everything seems fine,

but when I run this code I receive the following error :

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException ;

which means that the array index is out of reach. When I replace

```
ListBox.Items.Add(lines[reader]);
```

with

```
ListBox.Items.Add(lines[1]);
```

for example, it works fine. This means the issue comes from the "reader" int but I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Your `count` and `reader` (and `repeat` by extension) are all starting at `1`.  Indexes start at `0`.  It looks like you have way too many variables that you're trying to keep in sync here.  When looping over your collections, you can just use the `i` in the loop to index the items.  `count`, `reader`, and `repeat` all seem entirely unnecessary here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code? Do you want text in the clipboard broken apart into separate lines and added to the list box?

Comment: `ListBox.Items.AddRange(Temp.Split("\n", StringSplitOptions.None))`?

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. Every times a line breaks, a new item should be added in ListBox.

Comment: Ignoring lack of data that causes the problem in the question itself... the code shown is expected to fail - you counting number of lines one way but than splitting lines using *different* separator that may indeed lead to different number of lines. Very confusing why you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're starting your counter variables at `1`, then using that as an index into the array, but array's are zero-based in c# so you're essentially skipping the first item at `0` and then trying to access an item that's out of the bounds of the array.

It's also not accurate to count the `\n` characters and expect that to be equal to the number of `Environment.NewLine` instances.

It also seems you have a lot of unnecessary variables to track counting. Instead, your code could be reduced to:

```
string temp = Clipboard.GetText();
        
string[] lines = temp.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    ListBox.Items.Add(lines[i]);
}
```

Or, you could just do it all in one line:

```
ListBox.Items.AddRange(
    Clipboard.GetText().Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None));
```